# How do you mount conduit to a wall so that it stands off a standard box distance?

Tags: electrical, conduit, junction-box, support, emt

I'm running 1/2" EMT conduit between [single-gang surface-mount boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-City-1-Gang-4-in-2-1-8-in-D-New-Work-Metal-Utility-Box-5837112-25R/202590841). The holes for the boxes are slightly set away from the wall so that the conduit does not mount flush against the wall. I have found various types of [single screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C3YCDF6) and [double screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NLOK8RW) support clips that are intended for holding the conduit flush to the wall, but that would require an offset fitting at each box.

It seems that my options are to:

1. Strap the kind of it down and let it bend.
2. Use an offset fitting at each box.

**Question:**

If the distance from the wall to the box fitting a standard length, then what kind of strap or clip would you use to avoid offset fittings, even if it sticks up away from the wall by a small amount? (or do you simply use offsets at each box and strap it flat to the wall?)

Comment: With EMT you don't have to do an offset fitting, you can do a little bend right in the pipe.

Comment: Here in the UK, we would use what are known as "spacer bar saddles" for this. Not sure if they exist on your side of the pond.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1\2" EMT lends itself to bending very easily. And incorrect bends are easy to "adjust." A little practice with a bender will have you making great box offset bends in no time.
I will typically place the pipe flush with the hook of the bender shoe, then bend the smallest bend possible. It's a by "feel" bend for me, rather than a measured angle. As soon as I feel the pipe "give" a little, stop. Slide pipe thru the bender about 1.5", rotate 180 degree and repeat same bend.
If you use the weld seam as a guide, it is easy to ensure your bends are 180 degrees to each other. Just line the weld up either straight up or down in shoe, or left and right. Most benders have marks or edges that indicate the four 90 degree positions.

I avoid the conduit hangers as the give too much offset for 1\2".

Comment: "Slide pipe thru the never about" you may want to [edit] to clarify that bit. Unless "thru the never" is an electrician term for some part of a pipe bender. If so, clarify for the uninitiated would be helpful, too.

Comment: @FreeMan Only electricians who listen to a lot of Metallica. :)

Comment: That took a minute to kick in, @ChrisO, but it's funny now that it has!

Comment: Also, there's another typo in this answer that, typically, applies more to plumbers than electricians. It should probably be fixed during the [edit], too. ;)

Comment: Here is a reference with the offset and the "shrink" for a bend - very small shrink for this small offset requirement https://www.kleintools.com/sites/kleintools/files/instructions/Conduit%20Bender%20Guide.pdf

Comment: FWIW bending also allows the "pull" to be easier than the fittings

Comment: A vidieo for bending with 10deg angles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rNrEak1K9o

Comment: typical box 3/8 in offset 2 marks 2 1/4 in apart - 10 deg. each bend 180 deg offset. Basically 180 is the opposite side of the conduit. - shrink will be super small and prob not even a factor with the fittings on each end at the box

Comment: I'm not one to DV so I won't but I fail to see how this answers  the OP's question. The OP isn't asking for a lesson on how to bend conduit offsets, he's not even mentioning a bender at all.

Comment: I'd agree with you, @JACK, but the OP has accepted it, so maybe he's willing to learn to bend pipe...

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to get a conduit bender, you can use conduit hanger clamps like the one shown below from Home Depot. The clamp fastens to the wall and holds the conduit away from the wall.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you're using EMT and if wall-to-box offsets are the *only* thing you want to do (which is unlikely) and if you really don't want to learn to use a bender (or you're getting there, but slowly, and the job needs to get done) ... there's a solution in a box, the EMT offset connector.   It does exactly what you want, it connects EMT at a small, adjustable offset.  It has its limitations and because of the collar at the EMT end it won't be dead flush with the wall, so it won't look totally beautiful.

You'll probably want to do some other bends so maybe it's a good time to learn.  But this part is sometimes useful.

[image]

Comment: It also doesn't take too many of these to cost more than a bender, so if you're doing a lot the payoff isn't too far in the future

Comment: My local big-box store sells these for less than $2.50, but even if you put in a box offset, still need a connector which is ~$2, so you're really only saving $0.50. The cheapest bender they sell is $40 so it would take 80 of these before the tradeoff is worth it

Answer (score 5):

When confronted with that situation, I resort to a conduit bender.  You  can put a couple of small bends in the EMT .  It takes a bit of practice, but it's really not all that hard.

Comment: 40 years ago I used to know the math to make tube bends for a whole tube from end to end.   For something like this, guessing does a good enough job.

Comment: typical box 3/8 in offset 2 marks 2 1/4 in apart - 10 deg. each bend 180 deg offset.  Basically 180 is the opposite side of the conduit. - shrink will be super small  and prob not even a factor with the fittings on each end at the box

Answer (score 3):

Since bending attractive offsets is a skill that continues to elude me, I employ a mix of "leave it straight and let it stand off" and "let the strap bend it flush".

- For 1/2" and 3/4", I just let the strap pull them close to the wall - to me, the slight bend is usually less noticeable than a coupler+offset fitting would be.
- For larger pipe, 1-1/2", 2", and up, I use a spacer such as a bushing, uni-strut, or wood block to hold the straps tight, keeping the conduit straight and maintaining spacing from the wall.

Comment: My bender has marks on it and I just used a section to practice while carefully watching the marks that I used.

Comment: Ref: here for "offset bends" https://www.kleintools.com/sites/kleintools/files/instructions/Conduit%20Bender%20Guide.pdf